# ansible-playbook without --ask-vault-pass?

Tags: file, ansible, passwords, ansible-vault

How can I skip entering the vault password for an ansible playbook?

I run the playbook with `--ask-vault-pass` option, but I do not want to keep entering the vault password every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your environment the path to the file to store the vault password (to make the change permanent, add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file):

```sh
export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txt
```

Write the vault password to that file:

```sh
echo "my_password" > ~/.vault_pass.txt
```

Run your ansible playbook without the option `--ask-vault-pass`:

```sh
ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml
```

**REFERENCES:**

> **Setting a default password source**
>
> If you don’t want to provide the password file on the command line or if you use one vault password file more frequently than any other, you can set the `DEFAULT_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` config option or the `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` environment variable to specify a default file to use. For example, if you set `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txt`, Ansible will automatically search for the password in that file. This is useful if, for example, you use Ansible from a continuous integration system such as Jenkins.
>
> The file that you reference can be either a file containing the password (in plain text), or it can be a script (with executable permissions set) that returns the password.

Ansible docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#setting-a-default-password-source

---

- What are best practices for using Ansible Vault on public CI's and Source Control Repositories like BitBucket?: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/709
- How to store/retrieve multiple ansible-vault passwords within/from a single file: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12927
- What is Ansible's config equivalent of `--vault-password-file`?: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/703

Comment: Can also be added to your ansible.cfg under the section `[defaults]`; key `vault_password_file`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-vault-password-file. That's possibly more convenient than adding it to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: Thank you, this is a good method to know!